# -[__NSCFNumber objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

So I have been stuck on this for a while now and I have looked through many many posts on Stackoverflow but I still can't seem to figure out how to solve the problem. It seems to me that "dict" is supposed to be converted to a string so I have tried that in many ways, such as using `NSString *myString = [NSNumber stringValue];`, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", dict[@"id"]];` and a few others. Here is the code:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.params) {
    NSString *value = dict[@"id"];

    if (value) {
        [parameters appendFormat:@"&ids[]=%@", value];
    }
}
```

The error I get is on this line: `NSString *value = dict[@"id"];`

The output on the console shows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb00000000000a313'
```

I think the problem is that it does not seem to convert to a string properly. The line shows dict as an NSCFNumber (long)2609. How can I convert it to a string?

Comment: Are you sure `self.params` contains ONLY `NSDictionary` objects? It seems that there is a `NSNumber` object and not a `NSDictionary` object in it.

Comment: @Larme ohh, self.params contains one `NSDictionary` object and one `NSNumber` object

Comment: @Larme how can it be converted though?

Comment: Do you mean `for (id object in self.params){if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){//do you stuff}else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){//do other stuff}}?` I don't understand what you mean by "converting".

Comment: use [NSString stringWithFormate:@"%@",dict[@"id"]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// try like this it will work

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.params) {
if([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
  NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict[@"id"]];

  if (value) {
      [parameters appendFormat:@"&ids[]=%@", value];
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `self.params` data must contain an NSNumber. As soon as you get to the number and try to fetch a key, you crash.

You need to clean up your data, or write code that checks the class of each object in the array before attempting to fetch key values from it.

You could modify your loop like this:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.params) 
{
    if (![dict isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class])
    { 
      NSLog("Non-Dictionary object %@ found. Skipping.", dict)
      continue;
    }
    NSString *value = dict[@"id"];

    if (value) {
        [parameters appendFormat:@"&ids[]=%@", value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  [self.params enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
     if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

    // Do whatever you want
    }
}];
```